# Converting string to list of dictionaries using Python

Tags: python

I have code as follows:

```
try:
    relations = open(file_name, "wb")      
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(file_name), test)         
    relations.close()  # Closes the local file        
    ftp.quit()  # Closes the ftp connection
    print("FTP Connection quited.")        
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: File {0} could not be downloaded. {1}".format(file_name, str(e)))
```

And the test function is as follows:

```
def test(data):
    data_n = json.dumps(data.decode('utf-8'))

    pdb.set_trace()
    pass
```

I want to download the file from ftp server using python and read it without writing it locally.

In this case in `test` function in `data_n` i get:

```
'"CODE;MATCHCODE;\\r\\nK902154;VANHOVEGARAGES;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\\r\\nK902191;CARAVENUESTAR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\\r\\nK902192;CARAVENUESTAR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"'
```

How can I convert it to the list of dictionaries as follows:

```
result = [
    {
        "CODE": "K902154",
        "MATCHCODE": "VANHOVEGARAGES"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "K902191",
        "MATCHCODE": "CARAVENUESTAR"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "K902192",
        "MATCHCODE": "CARAVENUESTAR"
    }
]
```

Comment: It looks like you’re getting actual backslashes in that string, instead of newlines — is that correct?

Comment: @TomZych Yes. Its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
s = '"CODE;MATCHCODE;\\r\\nK902154;VANHOVEGARAGES;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\\r\\nK902191;CARAVENUESTAR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\\r\\nK902192;CARAVENUESTAR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"'
result = []
for i, v in enumerate(s.split(r"\r\n")):
    if i == 0:
        keys = v.strip().strip(';"').split(";")    #Get Keys
    else:
        result.append(dict(zip(keys, v.strip().strip(';"').split(";"))))     #Form dict. 

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'CODE': 'K902154', 'MATCHCODE': 'VANHOVEGARAGES'},
 {'CODE': 'K902191', 'MATCHCODE': 'CARAVENUESTAR'},
 {'CODE': 'K902192', 'MATCHCODE': 'CARAVENUESTAR'}]
```

Comment: Updated snippet. Can you try this?